# Cannot use 'VM' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead

Tags: android, koin

So previously this code was working fine (`2.0.1`).

```
abstract class ActivityBaseViewModel<out VM : ViewModel>(clazz: KClass<VM>) : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected val viewModel: VM by viewModel(clazz)
```

Then I updated Koin to `2.2.2` and now it can't compile this code:

> Cannot use 'VM' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no alternative function like this anymore.

So another solution would be like this:

base view model activity (or fragment)

```
abstract class ActivityBaseViewModel<out VM : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected abstract val viewModel: VM

    ...
}
```

and then in a specific activity (or fragment):

```
class MainActivity : ActivityBaseViewModel<MainActivityViewModel>() {

    override val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModel()
    
    ...
}
```